# js append method issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say i append `<li>` elements inside multiple `<ol>` simultaneously using a single click handler.
I have this method where i remove the closest li (see `function button_click`) using a button,but i want both li's i added at the same time to be removed,how could i target the second one ?

I thought to place a hidden remove button to the second one and make it click the same time,using the same remove function,but then again i need to target somehow the correct corresponding li at `#orderedList2`,any ideas ?

```js
var count = 0;
function button_click(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  var litg = tgt.closest("li");

  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
        litg.remove()
  }
}

function addLis1(){
  var ol1 = document.getElementById("orderedList1");
  count++;
  var li = document.createElement("li")

  var input = document.createElement("input")
  var remButton = document.createElement("button")
  remButton.className = "remove"
  remButton.innerText= "REMOVE " + count
  remButton.addEventListener("click",button_click)

  li.append(input,remButton)

  ol1.append(li);
}

function addLis2(){
  var ol2 = document.getElementById("orderedList2");

  var li = document.createElement("li")
  var label = document.createElement("label")
  label.innerText = "TEST " + count


  li.append(label)

  ol2.append(li);
}
```

```css
input{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
ol{
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  padding-left :27px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:3px;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type = "button" value = "ADD INPUTS" onclick = "addLis1();addLis2()">
  <ol id="orderedList1">1</ol>
  <ol id="orderedList2">2</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while adding, set the `id` attribute of the `li` element like `ol1_li_{count}` and `ol2_li_{count}`. get the `id` of `litg` and then generate the other `li` in other `ol`. Then `getElementById`, remove the element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could lookup the appropriate element by index, as you add them together they will have the same index

```
function button_click(e) {

  const tgt = e.target;
  var litg = tgt.closest("li")
   var idx = [...litg.parentElement.childNodes].indexOf(litg) // get index of clicked item
 
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
    litg.remove()

  }
  var ol2 = document.getElementById("orderedList2");
  var list2Nodes = [...ol2.childNodes];
  list2Nodes[idx].remove() // remove the item from list2 with that index
}
```

Live example:

```js
var count = 0;

function button_click(e) {

  const tgt = e.target;
  var litg = tgt.closest("li")
   var idx = [...litg.parentElement.childNodes].indexOf(litg)
 
  if (tgt.classList.contains("remove")) {
    litg.remove()

  }
  var ol2 = document.getElementById("orderedList2");
  var list2Nodes = [...ol2.childNodes];
  list2Nodes[idx].remove()
}

function addLis1() {
  var ol1 = document.getElementById("orderedList1");
  count++;
  var li = document.createElement("li")

  var input = document.createElement("input")
  var remButton = document.createElement("button")
  remButton.className = "remove"
  remButton.innerText = "REMOVE " + count
  remButton.addEventListener("click", button_click)

  li.append(input, remButton)

  ol1.append(li);
}

function addLis2() {
  var ol2 = document.getElementById("orderedList2");

  var li = document.createElement("li")
  var label = document.createElement("label")
  label.innerText = "TEST " + count

  li.append(label)

  ol2.append(li);
}
```

```css
input {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

ol {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 27px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 3px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="ADD INPUTS" onclick="addLis1();addLis2()">
  <ol id="orderedList1">1</ol>
  <ol id="orderedList2">2</ol>
</body>

</html>
```